# PHP file upload / move_uploaded_file not working, not like other questions

Tags: php, file-upload

I have looked through the five other similar questions on here and none of them have been able to solve my problem. I am uploading a CSV file that is 1657 bytes in size.

Here are some values from my php.ini file

`upload_max_filesize = 2M`

`post_max_size = 8M`

```
$file = $_FILES['csv'];

if (!isset($file)) {
    halt(HTTP_NOT_FOUND, 'This page could not be found on the web server');
}

if (substr(strrchr($file['name'], '.'), 1) != 'csv') {
    halt(500, 'Sorry but please upload a CSV file next time!');
}

if ($file['error'] != '0') {
    die('An error occurred during upload.<br />Error: ' . $file['error']);
}

$file_loc = '/home/x/tmp/up/' . basename($file['tmp_name']) . '.csv';

if (file_exists('/home/x/tmp/up/')) {
    echo 'the directory exists....<br/>';
}

if (file_exists($file['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'tmp file exists<br/>';
    echo filesize($file['tmp_name']) . 'b<br/>';
}

if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file_loc)) {
    echo 'Uploaded to: ' . $file_loc;
} else {
    echo 'something went wrong!' . print_r($_FILES['csv'], true);
    echo '<br />Upload Max Size: ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo '<br />POST Max Size: ' . ini_get('post_max_size');

}
```

And here is the generated output when I upload the file:

```
the directory exists....
tmp file exists
1657b
something went wrong!Array ( [name] => hm.csv [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel [tmp_name] => /tmp/php72p1VP [error] => 0 [size] => 1657 ) 
Upload Max Size: 2M
POST Max Size: 8M
```

I have already looked on PHP.net under the "common pitfalls" article which didn't lead to anything being fixed. Can anyone see what is wrong or give me some tips?

Comment: Check permissions on the directory.  Specifically, check that the web server has write permissions on the directory.

Comment: Does your PHP user have correct file permissions to access the directory you're trying to write the file to?

Comment: PHP creates a random value for the `tmp_name` parameter in the $_FILES array. You should **NOT** be using it as a permanent value for wherever you end up storing this file. And don't use string operations to parse filenames, and don't trust user file names to be accurate. a .CSV file could be called .txt and still be perfectly valid. Similarly, a hostile user can rename `nastygarbage.exe` to be `gooddata.csv` and get past your "security" system.

Comment: According to the manual, a warning is issued when a valid upload cannot be moved. Can you enable all error reporting and add the warning to the post?

Comment: @Corbin & Gareth yes it has 0766 permissions.

Comment: @MarcB, these files are in a private folder that is processed by another script so the exe is irrelevant considering no one will be able to see the files. As for the txt files that is fine and dandy I will allow all files to be uploaded and throw them out if it is unable to parse them in the second script.
As for the tmp_name parameter I am just using that for testing; this is not for production.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the error? <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); //your code ?>

Comment: @jeroen No errors were produced when I used `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, any other ideas?

Comment: @kstev: Anything in the PHP error log?

Comment: @Truth the error log has no errors related to this script.

Comment: @kstev: When attempting to manually write to a file at the same destination. Do you succeed of fail?

Comment: @Truth I guess I forgot to check this before posting! It seems as if I cannot make files or create directories with PHP scripts under the user that is running the LAMP server under any folder; including the public folder for the site. Now what?

Comment: @kstev: Is it possible you're having some sort of permission problem? Does the php process have permission to write files?

Comment: @Truth I am not entirely sure of whether or not this is the case, I have contacted my client to inform me of the situation as I do not have root access to the box it is running on to find out. I will let you know when I know more.

Comment: @Truth after quite a few exchanges with support they managed to fix the permissions issue which seemed to be a lot more work than necessary. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple exchanges with a tech at the hosting provider, they managed to give the folder the right permissions (I had tried 0777 before but it did not work). I believe some voodoo went on behind the scenes but this is `No errors in the error_log; I have set 777 permissions on /home/x/up` and the script began working.

Answer (score 1):

The following tips can be helpful.

```
1. The folder exists, check for spellings
2. Check the properties of the folder and make sure the permissions have read+write 0666
3. Make sure the file is within your public html root, otherwise double check the owner of the file, and make sure PHP Has read / write access to it.
4. Look for the logs i.e. Unable to move '/tmp/php6wlOg1' to 'upload/110216104651_00134_smooth_1440x900.jpg'
5. If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty. So set it according to your need.
```

Also set this to see if there are any errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or E_STRICT
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, unfortunately most of these had been previously mentioned in the comments...